# How can I prevent duplicate validation messages in Adobe Livecycle using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, livecycle-designer

I have a PDF containing multiple tables of data, each with multiple rows.  It is a Dynamic XFA-data PDF.  Validation works fairly well, as long as it is on one field only, but now I have a more complex validation.  If one field is populated, another field has to be populated, and vice versa.  I added validation JavaScript to the Foo field, and similarly to the Bar field.  The problem is that the validation messages are popping up multiple times for the same field, when I tab out of the field with an invalid value.  I have tried setting the xfa.event.rc to true/false (depending on whether the field is valid or not).  This is being used successfully in other fields on the PDF, but it seems to have no effect, and I can't find any documentation on xfa.event.rc, so it may be deprecated.  I think it used to be the return code.  I am using EC4 now, but this PDF was originally scripted for ES3.  Here is the JavaScript for the "Foo" validate event.  Selecting to display all the messages in the same box does not correct the problem.  It displays the same message multiple times.  I know this, because I added a line number variable to the message.

```
MyXmlRoot.FirstItemsList.ItemDataRow.Foo::validate - JavaScript, client)
this.validationMessage = "";
if (!this.isNull && this.rawValue != ""){
    var bar= xfa.resolveNode("MyXmlRoot.FirstItemsList.ItemDataRow.Bar");
    if (bar.isNull || bar.rawValue == ""){
       this.validationMessage = "A bar is required if a foo has been entered.";                 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this approach and it worked for me:

`Bar` field validate event:

```
MyXmlRoot.FirstItemsList.ItemDataRow.Bar::validate - (JavaScript, client)
script.validateFooBar(Foo, this);
```

`Foo` field validate event:

```
MyXmlRoot.FirstItemsList.ItemDataRow.Foo::validate - (JavaScript, client)
this.validationMessage = "A bar is required if a foo has been entered.";
script.validateFooBar(this, Bar);
```

`script` scriptobject:

```
MyXmlRoot.FirstItemsList.ItemDataRow.#variables[0].script - (JavaScript, client)
function validateFooBar(foo, bar){
    return !(!foo.isNull && bar.isNull);       
}
```

And here a picture of my hierarchy to make it clearer:
[image]
Now I only get one alert when

1. I delete the value of `bar` while `foo` is filled
2. I fill the value of `foo` while `bar` is empty

Comment: Thanks!  I will add that I found [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/livedocs/acrobat_sdk/9/Acrobat9_HTMLHelp/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Acrobat9_HTMLHelp&file=JS_API_AcroJS.88.582.html) that the validate method does not even listen for the event.rc, so it has no effect.  It makes no sense to me that if you try to return true or false from the code directly within the event scripting window, you will get a syntax error, but you may call a script that returns true or false.  The syntax error was why I attempted setting the event.rc in the first place.